# Silverlight on Windows Mobile?

Tags: silverlight, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6

Is it possible to develop Silverlight apps to run on Windows Mobile (pre-WP7) devices? I see all around searching on the web - in articles from 2008 and 2009 - that they were adding Silverlight support in WinMo 6.1, for example:

> **Internet Explorer Mobile**
>   The new version of Internet Explorer Mobile adds the ability to easily view full-screen Web pages and multimedia on the Web with a smartphone. Microsoft's press release states the new version takes advantage of "Internet Explorer 6 technologies" and supports industry standards such as H.264, Adobe Flash and Microsoft Silverlight. The update will be available to mobile phone partners in the third quarter of 2008, with the first Windows Mobile phones using the new version expected to be available by the end of 2008.

But I have found an [SL app](http://sl.weatherbug.com/?zip=98052) supposedly geared for mobile devices, but when I try going there in Pocket Internet Explorer on my WinMo 6.1 device, it shows me the "Get Silverlight" image button, but clicking it doesn't do anything.

So, what is the story? Is SL/WinMo development possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, not possible on WinMo. All the rave since MIX has been that it is available for Windows Phone 7 (successor to, and vastly different from, the WinMo devices). Here's a starter link: http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/devices/windows-phone/

Comment: Yah, I know WinPhone7 is supposedly going to support it, and personally I can't wait for it, but we do a lot of work with Motorola(Symbol)/Honeywell(HHP) scanner units, and I can't imagine those are going to port to WinPhone7 anytime soon. lol . Geez, this is disappointing that MS didn't push support for SL to WinMo 6. *sigh*

Comment: Scott Hanselman has a podcast on Win Phone 7:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HanselminutesPodcast206WindowsPhone7SeriesTheDeveloperExperienceWithCharlieKindel.aspx

Comment: @eidylon: Yeah, WinMo has been disappointing on many fronts. It kind of "lost" the smartphone market in just under 3 years. Most of the 6.0/6.1/6.5 innovation on that platform came from the OEM/ODMs, like HTC.

Comment: @Otaku:  Probably because behind closed doors MS working on something new

Comment: @Otaku - true; even on my personal phone, I don't use the built in UX much, and instead have it all tricked out with Spb software and shell. Looks a lot like the HTC type of interface. Oh well... 
@Anthony - guess that is probably true. Hope 7 does better; maybe a revitalization like Win7 did for the desktop.  :)

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: Actually, behind closed doors at MSFT it was a huge battle between the MBC group (the folks who own all mobility at Microsoft) and the UX group (the folks making Zune). It got really bad about a year ago with the Zune team producing, for all intents and purposes, what is current WP7 on their own. Then the MBC group escalated and got the UX team pulled into their own group. Finally, when SteveB's kid asked for an iPhone for their birthday, things changed.

Comment: @Otaku, is that a real story about Ballmer's kid? Pretty funny if it is!